# Handling a too big matrix equation

Tags: matrices, rotating

I was wondering if I could rotate the equation below to fit it on a page without compromising the font size.

I tried `landscape` and `rotating` packages to rotate the equation. In both cases I received error messages!

```
\begin{align*}
         &\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
         1                              & -P(N_k^a|L_k^c) & 0 & 0 & 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}) & 1              & 0& -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1})& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}^c) & 0 & 1              & -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1}^c)& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         0 & 0              &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2})& 1&0&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2})&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         0 & 0              &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2}^c)& 0&1&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2}^c)&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1})& 1              &0& -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1})\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1}^c)&0 & 1              & -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0 &0&\dots&0 &0 & -P(N_c^d|L_c) & 1
         \end{array} } \right]
         .\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kk}^{cn}|L_k^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2}^c)\\
         \vdots \\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
         \end{array} } \right]\\=
         &\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
         E(R_k|L_k^c) + P(N_k^s|L_k^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk}^{c+n}|L_k^c\right) \\
         E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}) + P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}^c) +P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}) + P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}^c) +P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c      \right)\\
         \vdots \\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}) + P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}^c) +P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c      \right)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
         \end{array} } \right]
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Your equation, even rotated, is too big (at least for the default settings on `a4paper` and `book`).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: What page dimension and margin settings do you use?

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is a strong structure in your matrix though I don't know how to express it without typing it out completely. So here is an attempt to describe it. By making it 8x8 and removing all the dots because currently they are wrong. `1 ... 0` doesn't make any sense and also ambiguous. The superscripted c terms and others can be grouped and that makes the matrix a block partitioned one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\makebox[\textheight][c]{\begin{minipage}{\paperheight}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
\begin{align*}
         &\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
         1                       & 0                       & 0                       &0              & -P(N_k^a|L_k^c) & 0                       & 0                      &0\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}^c) & 1                       & 0                       &0              & 0               & -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1}^c) & 0                      &0\\
         0                       & -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2}^c) & 1                       &0              & 0               & 0                       &-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2}^c) &0\\
         0                       & 0                       & -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1}^c) & 1             & 0               & 0                       & 0                      & -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1})   & 0                       & 0                       &0              & 1               & -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1})   & 0                      &0\\
         0                       & -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2})   & 0                       &0              & 0               & 1                       &-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2})   &0\\
         0                       & 0                       & -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1})   &0              & 0               & 0                       & 1                      &-P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1})\\
         0                       & 0                       & 0                       & -P(N_c^d|L_c) & 0               & 0                       & 0                      & 1
         \end{array} } \right]
         \cdot\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kk}^{cn}|L_k^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
         \end{array} } \right]\\
         &= \begin{bmatrix}K &L\\M&N\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}E^c_1\\E_2\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}
\end{sideways}
\newpage
where 
\begin{align*}
K_{mm}    &= 1, \\
K_{m,m-1} &= -P(N_{k+m}^d|L_{k+m}^c),\\
N_{mm}    &= 1, \\
N_{m-1,m} &= -P(N_{k+m}^a|L_{k+m}),\\
\end{align*}
and zero otherwise for $m=1,\ldots,c-(k+1)$. Similarly $L,M$ are diagonal matrices such that
\begin{align*}
L &=\operatorname{diag}\{-P(N_{k+m}^a|L_{k+m}^c)\}\\
M &=\operatorname{diag}\{-P(N_{k+m}^d|L_{k+m}) \}
\end{align*}
for $m=0,\ldots,c-(k+1)$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I would use K,L,M,N and put a description along the lines of

[image]

instead of fitting a beast in a **journal** paper. I need to warn you that this has the structure of a linear system `Ax=b` and I didn't include the operation on `b` in the document. But it is essentially a row permutation with 1,3,5,7,...2,4,6,....

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility, respecting the constrain to maintain the font size; the `align*` was placed in a `minipage` of `\paperheight` width; the `minipage` is in a `\makebox` to center the content; the whole construct is inside a `sideways` environment from the `rotating` package (I also reduced a little the separation between columns in the `array`s and set the page style to `empty`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\makebox[\textheight][c]{\begin{minipage}{\paperheight}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
\begin{align*}
         &\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
         1                              & -P(N_k^a|L_k^c) & 0 & 0 & 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}) & 1              & 0& -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1})& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}^c) & 0 & 1              & -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1}^c)& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         0 & 0              &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2})& 1&0&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2})&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         0 & 0              &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2}^c)& 0&1&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2}^c)&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1})& 1              &0& -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1})\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1}^c)&0 & 1              & -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0 &0&\dots&0 &0 & -P(N_c^d|L_c) & 1
         \end{array} } \right]
         \cdot\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kk}^{cn}|L_k^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2}^c)\\
         \vdots \\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
         \end{array} } \right]\\=
         &\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
         E(R_k|L_k^c) + P(N_k^s|L_k^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk}^{c+n}|L_k^c\right) \\
         E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}) + P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}^c) +P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}) + P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}^c) +P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c      \right)\\
         \vdots \\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}) + P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}^c) +P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c      \right)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
         \end{array}} \right]
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}
\end{sideways}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the expression is still too big, so perhaps some compromise with the font size would help here.

Here's another option; the equation was split in two `equation*` environments: in the first part, the big matrix is denoted `A`; in the second part, we give the meaning of the matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\makebox[\textheight][c]{\begin{minipage}{\paperheight}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
\begin{equation*}
         A
         \cdot\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kk}^{cn}|L_k^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2}^c)\\
         \vdots \\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1})\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
         \end{array} } \right] =
         \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
         E(R_k|L_k^c) + P(N_k^s|L_k^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk}^{c+n}|L_k^c\right) \\
         E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}) + P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}^c) +P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}) + P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}^c) +P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c      \right)\\
         \vdots \\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}) + P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1})  E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c      \right)\\
         E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}^c) +P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1}^c)   E\left(\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c      \right)\\             E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
         \end{array}} \right],
\end{equation*}
\hspace*{2.5cm}where
\begin{equation*}
A=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
         1                              & -P(N_k^a|L_k^c) & 0 & 0 & 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}) & 1              & 0& -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1})& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         -P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}^c) & 0 & 1              & -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1}^c)& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         0 & 0              &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2})& 1&0&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2})&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         0 & 0              &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2}^c)& 0&1&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2}^c)&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
         \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1})& 1              &0& -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1})\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1}^c)&0 & 1              & -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1}^c)\\
         0 & 0 & 0&0&0 &0&\dots&0 &0 & -P(N_c^d|L_c) & 1
         \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}}
\end{sideways}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not directly related to the question, but to denote multiplication in math expressions is better to use `\cdot` than just `.`.

Comment: Dear Gonzalo,

I do appreciate your time and detailed answer for my question.

I copied and pasted your code into my code. However, I did not get the same result you got here---in my .pdf file, the matrix is not written in an empty page; instead, it is written over part of my text!. I am using a style file which if for a specific journal. I am wondering that is why I get a bad outcome.

Comment: @Amir You can use `\clearpage` at the appropriate location: `\clearpage\begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}\clearpage`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the generic `array` environment, you could use the specialized `bmatrix` (matrix with brackets) environment of the `amsmath` package to economize on intercolumn whitespace. You'll still need to reduce the font size to make the entire expression fit in a single page, though. In the MWE below, I use the `\scriptsize` directive, which uses a `7pt` size (if your main document is set at `10pt`). I did see that you'd like to find a way to typeset the entire matrix equation without changing the font size, but I don't see how that objective may be achieved -- at least not if your paper size is either US-Letter or A4.

I've also replaced the simple "dot" (`.`) between the first two matrices with `\cdot`. I've also dispensed with all the `\left` and `\right` directives in the third matrix (column vector) because (in my opinion, at least) don't add clarity to that term.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12} % default value is 10
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry} % 'showframe' is there to indicate page margins
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
\begin{align*}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1   & -P(N_k^a|L_k^c) & 0 & 0 & 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
-P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}) & 1 & 0& -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1})& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
-P(N_{k+1}^d|L_{k+1}^c) & 0 & 1 & -P(N_{k+1}^a|L_{k+1}^c)& 0 &0&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
0 & 0 &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2})& 1&0&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2})&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
0 & 0 &  -P(N_{k+2}^d|L_{k+2}^c)& 0&1&-P(N_{k+2}^a|L_{k+2}^c)&\dots&0&0&0&0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1})& 1 &0& -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1})\\
0 & 0 & 0&0&0&0&\dots& -P(N_{c-1}^d|L_{c-1}^c)&0 & 1 & -P(N_{c-1}^a|L_{c-1}^c)\\
0 & 0 & 0&0&0 &0&\dots&0 &0 & -P(N_c^d|L_c) & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
E(\widetilde{A}_{kk}^{cn}|L_k^c)\\
E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1})\\
E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+1}^{cn}|L_{k+1}^c)\\
E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2})\\
E(\widetilde{A}_{k k+2}^{cn}|L_{k+2}^c)\\
\vdots \\
E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1})\\
E(\widetilde{A}_{k c-1}^{cn}|L_{c-1}^c)\\
E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[4ex] % some extra space
=
&\begin{bmatrix}
E(R_k|L_k^c) + P(N_k^s|L_k^c)   E (\widetilde{B}_{kk}^{c+n}|L_k^c ) \\
E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}) + P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1})  E (\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c   )\\
E(R_{k+1}|L_{k+1}^c) +P(N_{k+1}^s|L_{k+1}^c)   E (\widetilde{B}_{kk+1}^{c+n}|L_{k+1}^c   )\\
E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}) + P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2})  E (\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c   )\\
E(R_{k+2}|L_{k+2}^c) +P(N_{k+2}^s|L_{k+2}^c)   E (\widetilde{B}_{kk+2}^{c+n}|L_{k+2}^c   )\\
\vdots \\
E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}) + P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1})  E (\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c   )\\
E(R_{k+2}|L_{c-1}^c) +P(N_{c-1}^s|L_{c-1}^c)   E (\widetilde{B}_{kc-1}^{c+n}|L_{c-1}^c   )\\
E(\widetilde{A}_{kc}^{cn}|L_{c})\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```